# How to build target variable for supervised machine learning project

Tags: machine-learning, label, supervised-learning

I am quite new to machine learning with small experience and I did some projects.

Now I have a project relates to insurance. So I have databases about clients that I will merge to get all possible information about the clients and I have one database for the claims. I need to build a model to identify how risky the client based on ranks.

My question: I need to build my target variable that ranks the clients based on how risky they are, counting on the claims. I could have different strategies to do that, but I am confused about how I will deal with the following:
- Shall I do a specific type of analysis before building the ranks such as clustering, or I need to have a strong theoretical assumption matching with the project provider vision.
- If I use some variables in the claims database to build up the ranks, how shall I deal with them later. In other words, shall I remove them from the final data set for training, to avoid correlation with target variable, or I can treat them in a different way and keep them. 
- If I will keep them, is there a special treatment for them depending on whether they are categorical or continuous variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every machine learning project's starting point is EDA. First create some feature, like how often do they get bad claims or how many do they get. Then do some EDA to find which features are more useful. Secondly, the problem looks like classification. Clustering is usually harder to evaluate.

Answer (score 0):

In data sciences when you make a business model, EDA exploratory data analytics play a major role which includes data cleaning, feature engineering, filtering data. As mentioned how to build target variable, it all depends on the attributes you have and what model do you want to apply say linear regression or logistic or make a decision tree. You need to use those algorithms. But most importantly you need to find out the impacting variable. That's probably the core elation between the output and the given input and priority must be given accordingly. Also attributes which add no value must be removed as that would contribute to overfitting. 
You can do clustering too. And interesting thing is any unspervisoned learning could be converted to a form of supervised learning. Probably you can try to do logistic regression or do linear regression etc... And find out which model fits best to your project.